# Is there a way to build a query with eloquent based off input params?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

To explain this question better I'll just give an example:

Let's say I have a world records database and wish to create an api for it. Let's say I want to add a `search` route that takes in `GET` or `POST` parameters (let's keep it simple and just say `GET` for now). Is it possible to write a `search` controller method which uses something like an array as a parameter to Eloquent's `where` method while also utilizing a `like` parameter (MySQL `LIKE`)?

I have the following which works but only for exact values:

```
public function search()
{

    $params = Input::all();

    return Records::where($params)->get();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to:

```
public function search()
{
    $params = Input::all();

    $query = Records::newQuery();

    foreach($params as $key => $value)
    {
       $query->where($key, 'LIKE', "%$value%")
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

In the context of a scope, you can get fancier:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeFilter($query, $input = null)
    {
        $input = $input ?: Input::all();

        foreach($input as $key => $value)
        {
            if (Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $key))
            {
                $query->where($key, 'LIKE', "%$value%")
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }

}
```

Then you can do:

```
$filtered = User::filter()->get();
```

Or

```
$filtered = User::filter(Input::only('name', 'age'))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian, this is a much better way in this case. Edited.

Comment: I would put this pice of code into a query scope (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). Then your controller code would look more cleaner and the query building is happening within the model.

Comment: Thanks. If only this was in the documentation... At least it's in the API, but that isn't very helpful for new Laravel users. :)

Comment: Agreed, its like Easter egg documentation, well written but lots of hidden gems

Comment: Agree with passioncoder. This should be a query scope on the model or on a base model class. Then you could do Model::search($values);